# React Fullpage fp-auto-height-responsive and responsiveHeight not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, fullpage.js

I added fp-auto-height-responsive to the classlist of a slide and set responsiveHeight to 576. What I was expecting is that, on screens with view-width equal or lesser than 576px when I scroll on this slide, all of it contents should be scrolled completely through the screen before FullPage automatically scroll to the next slide. But it doesn't happen so, Fullpage scrolls to the next slide immediately i start scrolling on the slide which i added fp-auto-height-responsive to it's classlist. And when I try to scroll back, it displays only the second section of the slide i added the class to.

I have a component wrapper which I wrap around every page. It contains the react fullpage component.

```
<ReactFullpage
    licenseKey={process.env.REACT_APP_FP_LICENSE_KEY}
    scrollingSpeed={1000}
    navigation={true}
    normalScrollElements={".fp-scrollable"}
    responsiveHeight={576}
    render={()=>{

        return(

           <ReactFullpage.Wrapper>

                {children}
               
           </ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
            
        )
        
    }}

/>
```

Each page consists of several slides most of which look like this:

```
<div
      className='section w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center'
>
   {children}
</div>
```

This is how the slide which I want to have a custom height for looks like

```
<div
      className='section fp-auto-height-responsive w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center'
>
    {children}
</div>
```

I use Tailwindcss by the way, if that's relevant for the solution.

Comment: Can you post the code on codepen.io or here to see?

Comment: I have. Please look it up to see if it helps.

Comment: What is w-full h-full

Answer (score 0):

```
<div
      className = 'section fp-responsive fp-auto-height-responsive w-full flex justify-center items-center'
>
    {children}
</div>
```

---

After setting the responsiveHeight, then force the section to be as big as you want by using

```
.fp-responsive .fp-section,
.fp-responsive .fp-slide,
.fp-responsive .fp-tableCell{
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Or

```
.fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-section,
    .fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-slide,
    .fp-responsive .fp-auto-height-responsive .fp-tableCell{
        height: auto !important;
    }
```

Check if this helps you.

Or if not then you have set position absolute ot fixed to make this work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work o

Comment: @Hendrix: remove curly braces from responsiveHeight. Give like responsiveHeight : 576

Comment: Any error that is coming. Can you setup a working example on codepen.io? @Hendrix:

Comment: ok will certainly do

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-worker-7xbnwz hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve here. It seems to me you might want to use the `scrollOverflow` feature instead? This is the only option that allows you to scroll inside a section. See [this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html) and [this codepen](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/MzByMa).

Also, you mentioned the `width` of the screen but then you are using `responsiveHeight` instead of `responsiveWidth`.

For more info, see the definitions for those options in the [the fullpage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to scroll through a slide with height longer than that of the view-height, and when I'm done scrolling through that section, fullpage should be able to automatically detect that and scroll to the next slide which doesn't have the fp-auto-height-responsive class added to it

Comment: When you say "slide" do you mean, a horizontal slide? Or vertical section?

Comment: vertical slides

Comment: `fp-auto-height` is only used for sections smaller than the viewport. If you need a scrollable section you'll need to use the option `scrollOverflow: true` and fullpage.js will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

In react full page wrapper add setFitToSection false

```
<ReactFullpage
      licenseKey={""}
      scrollingSpeed={1000}
      navigation={true}
      setFitToSection={false}
      scrollOverflow={true}
      normalScrollElements={".fp-scrollable"}
      // responsiveHeight={576}
      render={() => {
        return <ReactFullpage.Wrapper>{children}</ReactFullpage.Wrapper>;
      }}
    />
```

In page.jsx, add fp-auto-height-responsive

```
<div className="page">
      <div className="section">section 1</div>
      <div className="section">section 2</div>
      <div className="section fp-auto-height-responsive">
        {/* Contains a child which has a height longer than the view-height
        What I'm expecting is for fullpage to scroll thoroughly through the section before
        automatically scrolling to the next section */}
          
        <div className="custom-height">section 3</div>
         <h2>Resize the height to less than 576px</h2>
      <h2>Section 1</h2>  
      <h2>Section 1</h2>  
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
      <h2>Section 1</h2>  
      <h2>Section 1</h2>  
      </div>
      <div className="section">section 4</div>
    </div>
```

Check if this is what you want.